# Get the legend of clicked column chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, stacked-chart

```
function selectHandler(e){
        var selectedItem = test.getSelection()[0];
        if (selectedItem.row != null) {
            // gets the location in x axis
            var loc_bar = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
          var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, selectedItem.column);
          debugger
          alert('The user selected ' + value);
        }
      }
```

This is my select handler, fired when clicked on the bar chart. I have a stacked bar chart and I want to know the legend related with the clicked stacked bar chart. I found a stackoverflow link related with pie chart but it is of no help for me. So is there a way to get the legend when clicked on a part of the stacked bar chart of google charts?

Comment: assign the event before drawing the chart...

Comment: @WhiteHat, yep I have done that but I am still unable to figure out how I can access the legend name related with the clicked part of stacked bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `getColumnLabel` to find the legend name for the column clicked...

```
var test = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

google.visualization.events.addListener(test, 'select', selectHandler);
function selectHandler(e) {
  var selection = test.getSelection();
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    console.log('the user selected ' + data.getColumnLabel(selection[0].column));
  }
}

test.draw(data, options);
```